# "DPInst.exe not supported on current OS"

Tags: windows, driver, dpinst

I have an installer that installs the USB serial drivers from FTDI. However on some computers (all of them running Russian Windows XP so it may be some language issue) the installation fails. I have tried to repeat it using a clean Russian Windows XP Professional SP3, but there it works so it's not a clear cut language issue.

The dpinst.log file says:

```
`INFO:   04/18/2013 14:05:34
INFO:   Product Version 2.1.0.0.
INFO:   Version: 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
INFO:   Platform ID: 2 (NT)
INFO:   Service Pack: 1.0
INFO:   Suite: 0x0100, Product Type: 1
INFO:   Architecture: X86.
INFO:   Interactive Windows Station
INFO:   Command Line: '"D:\Something\DPInst32.exe" '
INFO:   DPInst is a multi-lingual binary.
INFO:   ****************************************
INFO:   Current working directory: 'D:\Something\Drivers'
INFO:   Running on path 'D:\Something\Drivers'
INFO:   No valid 'dpinst.xml' file provided.
ERROR:  DPInst.exe not supported on current OS.
INFO:   Returning with code 0x80000000`
```

It is correct that I don't use a dpinst.xml file, but that should not be necessary. Or?

In the installer I run dpinst (32 or 64 depending on OS) with the switches `/c /q /sa /sw` but it's probably irrelevant since double clicking dpinst32.exe also gives an error. The dpinst version is 2.1

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue on Russion Win7x64 (the package was working perfectly on English Win7x64).

There are two versions of DPInst in WDK (redist\DIFx\DPInst folder): English (EngMui subfolder) and multilanguage (MultiLin subfolder). suddenly, it seems that the multilanguage version has problems with localized Windows.

I've replaced my original multilanguage DPInst.exe with the English one, and it solved the problem. English version was working fine on Russian Windows.

Comment: Did you have to include the localization files with the English version (meanining the dpinst.exe.mui files)?

Comment: As far as I remember, no. It just worked. Unfortunately, I don't remember the details and can't research it now.